# Android sample app Radar, all the PNG files are bad?...no get the raw file

Tags: android

not sure if others are experiencing this issue in the apps-for-android Sample Applications, but the Radar sample app PNG files are all bad...the Eclipse editor says: 
"libpng error: Not a PNG file"

I've also checked these PNG files on a couple of different PC's and none of the graphic programs can open or render the PNG files:

blip.png

ic_menu_metric.png

ic_menu_standar.png

icon.png

Here's the link to the sample app source for Radar, on the Google web site:
http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FRadar%2Fres%2Fdrawable

**Update:** rummaging around on the web, it appears that perhaps my Google Chrome browser is downloading/transfer everything in ASCII mode, rather than binary format...hmmmm...I'll try FireFox.

Well, it wasn't a browser thing...it appears that right-clicking on the PNG file on the Google app source folders, and doing a file-save-as is the wrong way to get these particular files.  What I found that worked is to click the png file so could see the change-log screen, then there is a 'file info' section that shows a raw file link, and that file link download would finally render properly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the source using SVN check out.  this will allow you to get the actual image files.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to 
open the png file in MS Paint 
re save it as png file.

Once I did that Eclipse was able to use that file in Android project.

This procedure converted the PNG to 32-bit format.

Android supports both 24-bit and 32-bit PNG's